# Our encrypted PDF got hacked

Tags: java, security, pdf, encryption, itext

We are encrypting our PDF with the following iText code. However, someone was able to edit our pdf (I am not sure how).

```
pdfWriter.setEncryption(null, null, PdfWriter.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS
    | PdfWriter.ALLOW_COPY | PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING,
    PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
```

Is there a better way for us to secure the pdf to prevent this?

Comment: The PDF is only as safe as the viewing program behaves nicely, i.e. respects the ALLOW... flags.

Comment: Why do you want to prevent editing?

Comment: This pdf contains system generated information, and it is not ment to be filled out by users.

Comment: Is it enough that you can detect if a pdf is generated by your program, or do you really want to prevent editing? And is it generated on a trusted computer(such as your server) or on an untrusted computer(the users computer)?

Comment: How do you know it was hacked?  Are you sure it's not just a bug in your pdf generation code?  "Garbage in/garbage out" and all that?  I know it's POSSIBLE, but this is the first time I've ever heard of it actually happening.

Comment: @Mark: google for "print encrypted pdf" and you'll find plenty of links to software to do that. I wouldn't suggest using any of those, but given how flimsy the "protection" is, I wouldn't be surprised if those tools do what they claim.

Comment: @Joachim: print sure, but EDIT?  *That* I've never heard of.  My question stands.

Comment: @Mark: how is editing a PDF any different? If you have the information to view/print it, you can also edit it. The only difference is that editing PDFs is not as common (even current OpenOffice.org/LibreOffice versions can do that, if you have the appropriate plugins). PDF is not a format *well suited* for editing, but it *can* be done.

Comment: @Joachim: Precisely.  While technically similar, I seriously doubt all those pdf print crackers do anything beyond printing... though I suppose they could simply strip out the owner security, or create a new, known, owner password.

Comment: @Mark: Sorry, been away for a week. Someone mailed our pdf to senior management, replacing information with "mickey mouse", bragging how they hacked it.  So it was successfully edited.

Comment: You can DETECT changes with a certificate signature.  You can PREVENT it with an "open" password only available to trusted individuals.  That's it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PDF Encryption and restriction of information relies **purely** on the goodwill of the authors of the viewer software to enforce that restriction.

Generally speaking, every application that has enough information to *display* the PDF has enough information to *print* the PDF, there's nothing really you can do about it.

Since there are plenty of open-source PDF viewers out there, it's very easy to produce a viewer that simply ignores those restrictions.

See [this explanation of the PDF encryption mechanism](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/Adobe/Gallery/anon21jul01-pdf-encryption.txt) for more detail.

Answer (score 3):

If your PDF is encrypted using 128 bits AES, then it is safe from someone that would not know the key, the most plausible explanation is that someone has had access to the key.

You may think about signing the PDF using RSA, that is a good way to make sure it has not been compromised.

Comment: Signing the PDF is the only way to ensure that the content is authentic and has not been modified.

Comment: No this is not, a CBC-MAC can be used too.

Comment: That's an excellent idea.  Sign the PDF.  Strong crypto that'll let you see the original if anyone has made changes.

Comment: @Leo: Yes, a MAC can be used, too. But the number of situations in which using a MAC makes sense is very limited as the MAC depends on a shared secret. Only persons knowing the secret can verify the MAC and additionally they will also be able to modify the document. I don't think that this would satisfy James Young.

Comment: @Robert That is exactly why I advised using RSA instead of CBC-MAC.

Comment: You don't need RSA (unless you're talking about the general algorithm) to sign the PDF, Acrobat Reader and a few 3rd party tools have the ability to sign it as well, as long as you have the key on your system or exported. It's a pain to generate the keys properly in openssl, so I just generate them in Reader and use them elsewhere.

Comment: Based on Joachim's response, I guess it doesn't matter how good the encryption scheme is?

Answer (score 1):

Encryption which prevents the viewing of a pdf works if the password is long enough.

The DRM features which allow viewing but disable other features such as printing, editing,... only work if the reader co-operates. The user can use a hacked or third party reader to circumvent such restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Add a user password.  It's the only one that really matters.  As you have no doubt gathered from the other answers, the owner password is a bit of a joke.

The USER password is strong crypto... up to 256-bit AES IIRC, though the original PDF crypto spec only allowed for 40-bit encryption due to US export restrictions.  Anything stronger than 40-bit was considered a "munition".  Goofy laws.

The OWNER password is not, it's more courtesy than anything else.  PDF libraries try to support it to one degree or another, but open source PDF libraries are a quick code change away from being "pdf crackers".

A blank user password means "use the predefined string of bytes listed in the PDF Specification that anyone can download".  The contents of the PDF are still encrypted, but everyone knows the password, so it doesn't do you much good.  PDF viewers/libraries substitute this string of bytes when given no password.

PS:

When calling `setEncryption`:

- a `null` open password means "a blank password" as I described above
- a `null` *owner* password means "generate a random one for me".

A random owner password means "no one can **legitimately** modify the PDF".. but that does not mean "no one can modify the PDF".